# Equivalent definitions of a Hodge structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, filtrations

Generally, a Hodge structure of weight $k$ on a finitely generated abelian group $H$ is defined as a decomposition of the complexification:

$$
H\otimes \mathbb C = \bigoplus_{p+q=k} H^{p,q},
$$

where the vector spaces $H^{p,q}$ must satisfy the condition $\overline{H^{p,q}}=H^{q,p}$.

If $H$ carries this structure, then it is possible to define the Hodge filtration as

$$
F^p(H)=\bigoplus_{k-q\geq p} H^{k-q,q} .
$$

However, it seems that if a filtration $F^\bullet(H)$ exists with the property that

$$
F^p(H)\cap \overline{F^q(H)}= 0 \qquad \mbox{ whenever } p+q=k+1
\tag{$\ast$}
$$

then a Hodge structure of weight $k$ exists on $H$ by putting

$$
H^{p,q}=F^p(H)\cap \overline{F^q(H)}.
$$

Now, in Peters and Steenbrink, it is said that $(\ast)$ is equivalent to say that $F^p(H)\oplus F^{k-p+1}(H)=H\otimes\mathbb C$, while on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_structure) this latter condition is also required (meaning that it might not be equivalent).

**Question 1.** Is it equivalent or not?

If the answer is yes, notice that the Hodge filtration satisfies much nicer properties than the required on  the existing descending filtration (for the Hodge filtration $F^p(H)\cap\overline{F^q(H)} = 0$ unless $p+q=k$), which makes me think that the Hodge filtration of associated given by the Hodge structure induced by the former filtration would be different. Isn't that absurd?.

**Question 2.** Either if the answer to question 1 is yes or not, how can one prove that indeed

$$
H\otimes\mathbb C= \bigoplus_{p+q=k} F^p(H)\cap\overline{F^q(H)} ?
$$

I can only see it if the filtration $F^\bullet(H)$ satisfies the same properties that the Hodge filtration.

Comment: In your statement (*) you mean that their intersection is non-zero?  What is the intersection supposed to be?  For the more general question, what if your two filtrations are the same, $F = F^\circ$ (sorry, I don't know how to do the filled in dot)?  Then how could one be an improvement of the other?

Comment: @JohnSamples Thanks for the correction. No, the intersection must be trivial, I've already corrected that. And I don't know what you mean, there is only a given filtration $F^\bullet(H)$ of $H\otimes C$. The bar denotes the complex-conjugate space. However, if such a filtration induces a Hodge structure, one can always defined the corresponding Hodge filtration, and I think the former and the latter are different (or at least I cannot prove they are the same).

Comment: PS: To fill the point use `\bullet`: $F^\bullet(H)$.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Sorry, I've been away but it looks like someone smarter than me already answered, thankfully.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately for you, I've had a headache because of the conflict between these exact references before.

**Wikipedia is correct, Peters and Steenbrink are not.**

**Question 1. Is it equivalent? No.**

Here's an example: Let $k=0$, let $H \cong \mathbb Z$. Let
$$
0= F_0 = F_1=\cdots ;\quad H \otimes \mathbb C= F_{-1}=F_{-2}=\cdots
$$
You can check that the condition in Peters and Steenbrink is satisfied, but this is not a Hodge structure of weight $0$, as all the graded pieces will vanish.

In general, take any Hodge structure of weight $k$. According to the condition in Peters and Steenbrink, it is automatically a Hodge structure of any weight $k'\ge k$, since the Hodge filtration is decreasing, which is never true.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your example can even be modified to get a filtration of finite length and still not define a Hodge struxturebof weight $0$. What about question 2 then?